# More than one endpoint exists with the name 'nova'

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

the command do not work, when I want to show the nova's endpoints:

```
openstack endpoint show nova
```

it will report error:

> More than one endpoint exists with the name 'nova'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check your endpoints, you will likely find that they reside in an Interface environment.

```
 % openstack endpoint list -c ID -c "Service Name" -c Interface --service nova
+----------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
| ID                               | Service Name | Interface |
+----------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 2d45aed973da34f7d28b8c9e410bba5e | nova         | public    |
| 7de83faa23d4ee5b39a8b7de45b8ee15 | nova         | internal  |    
| ab8374d8b8f233fe11cda487bfe98ad7 | nova         | admin     |
+----------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Similarily, you can filter only endpoints in a specific interface

```
% openstack endpoint list --interface public
```

For your command then use the ID instead of the name of the Service Name, e.g. this would give me the admin nova API:

```
openstack endpoint show ab8374d8b8f233fe11cda487bfe98ad7
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
openstack endpoint list --service nova
```

to show the endpoints.